# Xcode is not recognising my pods framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have found people with similar problems but not exactly the same.

I am using cocoapods for the first time, and Xcode is not recognising the Pods framework. So to ensure that it wasn't related to some existing XCode configuration, I created a brand new Xcode project (PodsTest), but the problem persists (as you can see below).

[image]

My podfile is also deliberately minimal with a single pod included:

```css
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'PodsTest' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'SwiftSocket'
  # Pods for PodsTest

end
```

On running pod install everything seems to be in order, the PodTest.xcworkspace is created.

[image]

Then in the project target within build phases, within the "link binary with library", the framework appears normally "Pods_PodsTest.framework"

[image]

I thought it would be easy to get to the bottom of this using a a brand new Xcode project, and having installed cocoapods for the first it should also be running the latest version and so be in a working state. Have I missed any steps that I need to follow? Or what would anyone suggest to look at? You can assume an untampered with Xcode project settings/configuration.

Comment: You should open the PodsText.xcworkspace and run it.

Comment: It clearly said that use the `xcworkspace ` after the pod successfully install, not sure what you trying to do with open the pod `xcodeproj`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something silly.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the cocoapods framework that you want to install is compatible with your current Xcode version. To solve this, give the version after the pods. Because if you don't give the version, it automatically installed the new version. For example:
`pod 'Charts'` to `pod 'Charts', '~> 3.2.1'`

or you can simply update your Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue happened because you did not added the SDK correctly.
So please follow the steps.

**1.In the project navigator, select your project.**

**2.Select your target.**

**3.Select the "Build Phases" tab.**

**4.Open "Link Binaries With Libraries" expander.**

**5.Click the + button.**

**6.Select your framework.**

**7.(optional) Drag and drop the added framework to the "Frameworks" group.**

After performing the above mentioned steps please clean your project and build again.

hop this will work , Thank you

Comment: Thank You Fansad. The perfect solution.

Comment: Thank you Fansad for the step wise solution.